# Cycles - Tweak Ambient Occlusion

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

Is a "Correct" way to tweak AO in Cycles? I enabled the AO Pass to add the Ambient occlusion in the compositing, but at the moment i multiply the AO and the render, everything that is in black AO background get black.I'm using a procedural texture BTW, the sculpt has a lot of polygons to unrwap and bake.Is there the better way to tweak the AO? Or even a workaround to the Multiply

[image]

The node Setup

[image]

Comment: Can you please show your node setup ?

Comment: Added the node setup, is quite simple, and i know the black pixel being multiply is the problem, but i don't know how to properly mask to only mutiply the object itself